# awk for text processing a cvs file

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a number of big *.cvs text files that looks like this:

```
    Word,Tag,Lemma
    Off,aa,off
    short,aa,short
    and,sfg3eþ,and
    tall,sþghen,tall
    deers,aþ,deer
    in,never,in
    Africa,nc,Africa
    frv.,aa,frv.
    ---,ta,---
    ,,
    All,nhfn,all
    allowed,lhfnsf,allow
    personell,c,personell
    aggr.,lheþsf,aggr.
    with,aþ,with
    23,ta,23
    as.,nvfn,as.
    sillable.,lheþsf,sillable.
    ,,
    Á,aþ,á
```

I need to process this file such that the first column be put in a list like this:

```
    {[Off short and tall deers in Africa frv],[All allowed personnel aggr. with 23 as syllable.],[Á......],...n]}
```

At the very end there needs to be a: ]}

What I have tried:

```
    awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";print"{["} /",,"/ {print"],["} END {print"]}"}' 079.cvs
```

Which just prints: 
{[
]}

I also found this:

```
    cat 080.csv | cut -d ',' -f3 >>D.txt
```

Which is actually quite useful:

```
    Off
    short
    and 
    tall
    ....
```

But actually is to "deep" file and missing the list elements.

Comment: It is not nice to unaccept an answer to be able to delete your question. If you used my help, be courteous. See your deleted question: [Producing number sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36344915/1983854).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{printf "{["; next} /^--/||!$1{if(a)printf "],["; a=0; next} {printf "%s ",$1; a=1} END{printf "]}"}' file
{[Off short and tall deers in Africa frv. ],[All allowed personell aggr. with 23 as. sillable. ],[Á ]}
```

Comment: This is very good, it prints out biggest portion of a file but ends with this: awk: weird printf conversion % 
 input record number 1303, file 079.csv
 source line number 1
awk: not enough args in printf(20% )
 input record number 1303, file 079.csv
 source line number 1

Comment: You check 079.csv 1303 lines ?

Comment: I was to late to omit biggest in my previous comment. Yes it processes the first 1303 lines.  The file has 331765 lines.

Comment: I think is field problem, code /^--/||!$1 , this field is not match. you can update you source content

Comment: line 1303:'20%,ta,20%'   --line 1304:'",",",",","' --another file, line n:'30--35%,ta,30--35%' -->stops on this line.

Comment: This actually prints overtime a sentence ends: foo...n . ],[       --which can be useful but what I need is: foo...n.],[Foo foo

Comment: Looking at the content of the files it's better to use /^,,/ for matching